# Assigning one property to another in Maven

Tags: java, maven-2

My Maven project has two properties which are used when filtering a persistence configuration file:

```
<database-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/${database-name}?autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;rewriteBatchedStatements=true&amp;amp;useServerPrepStmts=false&amp;amp;useCursorFetch=true</database-url>
<test-database-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/${test-database-name}?autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;rewriteBatchedStatements=true&amp;amp;useServerPrepStmts=false&amp;amp;useCursorFetch=true</test-database-url>
```

The properties need to be doubly-XML-encoded since the configuration file itself is an XML document and Maven resolves XML entities during resource filtering.

I'd like to be able to run my tests directly from my IDE, so I created a profile and set one property to another.

```
<database-url>${test-database-url}</database-url>
```

The problem is that Maven resolves the entities in the setting of the property, and then again during the filtering of the configuration file, which means that my configuration file is invalid XML.

Is there a way to set one property to another without resolving the XML entities?

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer but... why don't you use different values for the same property depending of the profile. For example, a (default) development profile would have:

```
<database.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app_dev</database.url>
```

And a test profile would have:

```
<database.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app_test</database.url>
```

And if this is not what you want, maybe having a single `database.url` property for the url and passing a system property like `-Ddatabase-name=app_xxx` for the name would do the trick.

But I may be missing something.

Comment: Our application supports many databses, and so profiles are already being used to assign the database-name, database-url and test-database-url properties.  I'm trying to avoid duplicating all the database profiles in "test" mode.  Also, the database name is (unfortunately!) dependent on the database being used, so setting it on the command line would required the mapping knowledge encoded in the POM.